# Re-initialize angularjs in a test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I'm writing some anuglarjs tests for a service that has some persistence to it. I'd like to:

1. Inject the service
2. Fill it with some data
3. Re-initialize angular (so that the service's singleton is re-initailzed"
4. Test that the service has what I put in it on step #2

I thought that I'd be able to call angular.mock.module inside my test to re-initialize it, but that's no good, it just throws errors that we can't configure after the injector has been created.

Test shown:

```
describe('commBuffer', function () {
  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('step'));

  it('persists buffers across sessions',inject(function(commBuffer,connectivity) {
    connectivity.isOnline = false;
    commBuffer.issue({ method: 'GET', url: '/api/data' });
    commBuffer.bufferSize.should.eql(1);
    angular.mock.module('step'); //How do I wipe out the current angular session and re-init it?

    //Does the commBuffer persist it's buffer between sessions?
    commBuffer.bufferSize.should.eql(1);
  }));

});
```

Any idea how to essentially re-initialize anguarjs inside of a test?

Comment: In your case, I think you don't need to mock a service, just inject the service and do tests normally on the service. You only need to mock if the service has dependencies on other services (mock the dependencies). I'm not sure if this is what you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23058784/unit-testing-a-angularjs-service/23059247#23059247

Comment: @KhanhTO I'm not sure we understand each other. I'm not trying to mock the service. I inject it just fine, but then need to essentially re-inject a new instance of it in a completely new angular 'context' to ensure that it persisted itself correctly.

Comment: Can you show code of the test that's "no good"?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can't reinitialise Angular mid-way in a test. But...

...you might be trying to test too much. Whatever your persistence layer is that `commBuffer` uses, you should probably mock it up before injecting it into your test, and test that `commBuffer` uses it as you expect. You then effectively trust that HTML5 storage persists as you expect it to. (Anything more will be for E2E/integration tests)

Say you're using HTML5 storage, which you access directly by `$window.localStorage`. You can mock this up as follows (just is just one example, there are other patterns, and all untested).

```
describe('commBuffer', function () {
  var localStorageMock, commBuffer, connectivity;

  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('step'));

  beforeEach(function() {
    // Clear before every test
    localStorageMock = {
      getItem: function(key) {},
      setItem: function(key, value) {}
    };
  });

  beforeEach(module(function($provide) {
    $provide.value('$window', {
      localStorage: localStorageMock
    });
  }));

  // You'll have to change the following for
  // the exact behaviour of commBuffer / bufferSize
  describe('on initialisation', function() {

    beforeEach(function() {
      // Your test buffer data
      spyOn(localStorage, 'getItem').andReturn('test-data');
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function(_commBuffer_, _connectivity_) {
      commBuffer = _commBuffer_;
      connectivity = _connectivity_;
    });

    it('gets the buffer from storage', function() {
      // Whatever the test needs to be to check the buffer
      // was retrieved from the mock storage service
      commBuffer.bufferSize.should.eql(1);
    });   
  });      
});
```

The above is a simple example. Depending on what `commBuffer` does, you might have to have more complicated spies/mocks setup for the service.